# Check if Windows OS runs in safe mode

Tags: windows, winapi

What Windows API call do I need in order to check whether the system booted in safe mode or normal mode?

Comment: There's some information on this on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837643).

Comment: Potentailly useful [question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/q/433765). See especially link in accepted answer.

Comment: You are not going to get Qt framework answers since the concept of safe mode does not exist on all systems supported by Qt.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand your idea, but look at `Windows registry`. Not sure about `QT` but `JAVA` allows editing `Windows registry` although registry do not exist in other systems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call [`GetSystemMetrics( SM_CLEANBOOT )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and look for a nonzero value.